# Merge two sql query for multiple output

Tags: mysql

I have these two query :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from chapter where chapterID =1")or die('Query failed');
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * from page where chapterID =1")or die('Query failed');
```

my php

```html
<?php 
      $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die ('could not connect to db:'. mysql_error());
      mysql_select_db('learn') or die('No db found');
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT chapter.cDescription, page.pageName, page.pageIcon, chapter.cTitle FROM chapter LEFT JOIN page ON chapter.chapterID=page.chapterID GROUP BY page.pageID,page.chapterID")or die('Query failed');
      
      while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query) )
      {
     
      echo "

                        <tr>
                            <td>
        <hr>
        <div class='chapter-container'>
        <div class='chapter-title' style='display: inline-block;float: left;'>
        <h3 style='margin-bottom: 22px;'>";
        
        echo $result['cTitle'];
        
        echo "</h3>
        <div class='chapter-description'>";
        
        echo $result['cDescription']; 
        echo "
        </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class='chapter-contents' style='display: inline-block;float: left'>
        <div class='contents-box' style='margin: 15px 20px;'>
       
                                        <a href='networking_terms.html' style='display: block'>";
                                           
           echo "<span class='".$result['pageIcon']."' ></span>";
                                      
           echo "<span class='progress-title' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title='Get familiar with the terms!'>";
           
           echo $result['pageName']; 
           
           echo "</span>
                                        </a>";
      }
    
     ?>
```

I want to merge these two in one query. 
How can i merge the two query? 
**Note: that 1 chapter has many pages**

What i want to achieve
[image]

What i am actually getting
[image]

Comment: As per yur second attached image plz share the code u cant use resultant array in loop as like that it will repeat u need to modify yur array. Yur query is fine now. Show yur code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

Try this:

```
// make an array
$yourData
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query) )
{

$yourData[$result['chapterId']][] = $result;

}
```

Than print it in your HTML, idea is:

```
foreach( $yourData as $key => $value ){

  //your stuff
  echo $value[0]['chapterName']."<br>". $value[0]['chapDesc']; // print chaprer name
  foreach( $value as $final ){

  //your html stuff
  echo $final["pageName"]; // print page name

  }
}
```

**UPDATE 3 (with original HTML):**

```
$myArr = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $myArr[$value['cTitle']][] = $value;
}

foreach ($myArr as $key2 => $value) {
echo "

<tr>
<td>
<hr>
<div class='chapter-container'>
<div class='chapter-title' style='display: inline-block;float: left;'>
<h3 style='margin-bottom: 22px;'>";

echo $value[0]['cTitle'];

echo "</h3>
<div class='chapter-description'>";

echo $value[0]['cDescription']; 
echo "
</div>
</div>

";

foreach ($value as $key => $value2) {
echo "
<div class='chapter-contents' style='display: inline-block;float: left'>
<div class='contents-box' style='margin: 15px 20px;'>

<a href='networking_terms.html' style='display: block'>";

echo "<span class='".$value2['pageIcon']."' ></span>";

echo "<span class='progress-title' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title='Get familiar with the terms!'>";

echo $value2['pageName']; 

echo "</span>
</a>";
}
}
?>
```

**Side Note:**

I suggest you to use mysqli_* or PDO instead of mysql_* becuase its deprecated and not available in PHP 7

Comment: @neha for suppose if any chapter not have any page than u need this chapter?

Comment: And did u try with RIGHT join? @neha

Comment: i tried the `LEFT JOIN` but it is returning me duplication for chapters. My results are displayed in a table

Comment: Than use group by chapter.chapterId at end of query. @neha

Comment: no duplication now but i have two pages with chapterID = 1 (chapterID is foreign key here). the seond page with chapterID=1 is missing

Comment: @neha group by pageid, chapterid.... use both together or just try with page id... and chk the result of both combinations

Comment: `...GROUP BY chapter.chapterID,page.chapterID`
same the page with common chapterID is missing

Comment: It will not work. Group by pageid, chapterid... I said this.. @neha

Comment: `mysql_query("SELECT chapter.cDescription, page.pageName, page.pageIcon, chapter.cTitle
FROM chapter
LEFT JOIN page
ON chapter.chapterID=page.chapterID GROUP BY page.chapterID,page.pageID;")` not working-please correct me if i wrote the query wrong

Comment: ("SELECT chapter.cDescription, page.pageName, page.pageIcon, chapter.cTitle FROM chapter LEFT JOIN page ON chapter.chapterID=page.chapterID GROUP BY page.pageID;    what is the result of this query @neha

Comment: all displayed but the chapter is duplicated for that particular page

Comment: It means u need to chapterid after page id in group by as I suggest ..... group by page.pageid, page.chapterid @neha

Comment: same thing- duplication. please see the edit of the post i am putting an image of what i want to achieve

Comment: @neha yes I have checked tell me is pageid not unique id? Or page name have unqiue nam?

Comment: Last thing if any chapter not have any page than u need this record? @neha

Comment: no if there no pages in that chapter i don't need it

Comment: @neha as per yur second attachment. Can you share your code how u r using in loop?

Comment: Ohh my friend yur query is fine no need to use left join. Just show yur code @neha

Comment: done do check it. In fact the reason of wanting to merge the two queries is replace the `=1` by a count

Comment: @neha no need to use left join yur qurry in fine I have updated my answer basic idea u can test it without html than use html.

Comment: the pages  are not displayed according to their chapters.

Comment: still no, can you please try style according to my screenshot provided.maybe i am not doing it right

Comment: `      $yourData=array();
      while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query) )
      {
       $yourData[$result['cTitle']][] = $result;
       
      }
     
     foreach( $yourData as $key => $value ){

         //your stuff
        echo $value[0]['cTitle']."<br>". $value[0]['cDescription']."<hr>"; // print chaprer name
        foreach( $value as $final )
        {

        //your html stuff
        echo $final["pageName"];  // print page name

        }
       `

Comment: share the screen shot after implementation... @neha this will return u what u required... but i dont know about yur html desing.

Comment: made it work too and its similar as yours.
Thanks a ton

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100289/discussion-between-devpro-and-neha).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a dataset containing the result from both queries? To do this, you should use a UNION:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Chapter WHERE ChapterID = 1
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM Page WHERE ChapterID = 1") or die('Query failed');
```

For this to work, the columns of the tables must match in both number and type. If they don't, you must select the spicific columns in both select statements and those should match.

Comment: If I got it wrong, please tell me what this is for? :)

Comment: made the required changes but following is not identifying the columns of my page table